# net-snmp what's wrong with the OID?

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, snmpwalk

I have requested for a `PEN(Private Enterprise Number)` and got it. The *PEN is 50743*. I have a very simple `MIB` which looks like this:

```
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN     

IMPORTS    
    MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, NOTIFICATION-TYPE,
    Integer32, enterprises  FROM SNMPv2-SMI
;

sampleSnmp    MODULE-IDENTITY    
    LAST-UPDATED "201709120200Z"    
    ORGANIZATION "Company Name"    
    CONTACT-INFO    
        "myMail@comName.com"
    DESCRIPTION    
        "A test MIB"    
    REVISION    "201709220200Z"    
    DESCRIPTION    
        "initial Draft"    
    ::= { enterprises 50743 }   


sampleSnmpScalar  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { sampleSnmp 1 }

sampleVar OBJECT-TYPE    
    SYNTAX Integer32    
    MAX-ACCESS  read-write    
    STATUS  current    
    DESCRIPTION    
        "A simple test object"    
    ::= { sampleSnmpScalar 1}

END
```

After compilation(sampleVar.c sampleVar.h) and configuration, when I do `snmpwalk`, I get something like this:

```
root@ashish:~# snmpwalk -v 2c -c ncs 192.168.5.13 SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmpScalar.0 = INTEGER: 1
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.2.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = STRING: "/bin/echo"
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.3.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = ""
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.4.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = ""
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.5.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 5
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.6.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 1
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.7.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 1
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.20.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 4
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.2.1.21.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 1
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.3.1.1.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = ""
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.3.1.2.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = ""
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.3.1.3.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 1
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.3.1.4.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51 = INTEGER: 0
SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp.4.1.2.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51.1 = ""
```

**What's wrong with the OID?** I mean, to use `snmpget`, I have to query like:

`snmpget ... sampleSnmp.2.1.5.18.46.49.46.51.46.54.46.49.46.52.46.49.46.53.48.55.52.51`

**UPDATE:** `snmptranslate` works just fine:

```
root@ashish:~# snmptranslate -IR -On SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmp SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleSnmpScalar SAMPLE-SNMP-MIB::sampleVar
.1.3.6.1.4.1.50743
.1.3.6.1.4.1.50743.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.50743.1.1
```

Any suggestions about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you